# how to check which Extensions are installed on a Magento site?

Tags: extensions, uninstall-module

I am about to take over an existing Magento 1.9 store and one of the tasks would be to 'clean up' no longer used extension. Two questions in that regard (I'm fairly new to Magento in general, so those may be pretty novice questions):

1. is removing an Extension a good idea or even possible in the first place? I coudl imagine there may be a risk of mesing up the backenend/database? If *'not a good idea'* ... can you hide extensions from sight in the backend and likewise at least clean up the interface?
2. how can you check which extension are installed on a Magento store (backend, or ftp)? I guess you should be able to see it via ftp, but where exactly to look (guessing somewhere in the `/app/code/` directory. Maybe everything inside `~/community` & `~/local`)?

Comment: See this link :  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48838/how-many-way-to-enable-and-disable-custom-magento-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to safely "uninstall" extensions from Magento 1.9. but there is an easy way to see which ones are installed and disable them.

1. In your FTP go to app/etc/modules. This is where all the extension
   xml files are located.
2. Create a new folder here called "disabled".
3. Move the
   xml file of the extension you wish to disable to this new folder (app/etc/modules/disabled).
4. Now log into the Magento backend and go to
   System > Cache Management. Click "Flush Magento Cache" to have Magento recognize the changes.

This is not the "correct" way. but it's the fastest and easiest; and it's even recommended by [some extension developers](https://support.magerewards.com/article/1543-how-do-i-disable-magerewards) and [hosting providers](https://www.sonassi.com/blog/upgrading-magento).

Comment: that seems much easier and more visually easy to grasp then editing the respective xml file (which is being suggest in the posts that have been menioned on the previous comments (thanks for those btw).  As you say this wasn't the "correct" way. Is there anything speaking against that practice? Also does it matter whether the module/extension disabled in that way is a 'local' or 'community' module?

Comment: added your method to [another thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48838/how-many-way-to-enable-and-disable-custom-magento-extension/236904#236904). hope you don't mind

Comment: @magpieninja This method won't allow you to see all the modules in the backend of the Magento admin, but that information is honestly not very useful if you also have access to the file system. A module being _community_ or _local_ doesn't change its behavior, just the load order.